# Error create React Native CLI QuickStart?

Tags: reactjs, native

I try to create my first app with React Native, but I have this problem :

```
✖ Installing Bundler
error Ignoring executable-hooks-1.6.1 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine executable-hooks --version 1.6.1
Ignoring ffi-1.15.5 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.15.5
Ignoring gem-wrappers-1.4.0 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine gem-wrappers --version 1.4.0
```

How can I solve ?

Answer (score 1):

Running bundle install in the root directory, then pod install in /ios

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).